# What is promotional feature in git?

Tags: git

I am new to Git, and i am not a native English speaker, so I am a bit at a loss trying to understand this abstract:

"Over the course of time, you'll make some changes you know will be undone. Be it a **promotional feature**, patch, or other temporary change someday soon you'll want to undo that work."

It is about commiting changes that you will undo in future. I cannot understand what is a promotional feature here, and why is it a temporary thing?

Thanks

Comment: It's not something that Git does, it's something that a business wants the program to do for a while, and then be able to easily remove.

Comment: @AlisterBulman thanks! I didn't think in that direction. Now it's clear